# Is $\mathcal E\to f_*f^*\mathcal E$ an isomorphism for $\mathcal E$ a free sheaf?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

In the context of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/638501/hartshornes-exercise-ii-5-1-projection-formula) about the projection formula for sheaves, Giulio Bresciani answers and uses that the natural morphism $\gamma \colon \mathcal E\to f_*f^*\mathcal E$ is an isomorphism when $\mathcal E$ is free. As I said in my comment I don't understand why this is true, considering for example $\mathcal E=\mathcal O_Y$ we would get $\mathcal O_Y\cong f_*\mathcal O_X$ which is not always true.

So is it true and under what assumptions do we have an isomorphism (except $f$ being a fibre) ?

Comment: It's not true in general - your choice of $\mathcal{E}=\mathcal{O}_X$ is good, and there is good general discussion [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/63301/when-will-the-pushforward-of-a-structure-sheaf-still-be-a-structure-sheaf) about when $f_*\mathcal{O}_X\cong\mathcal{O}_Y$. Unfortunately it looks like there are several wrong answers over there; it would be nice to clean them up.